# Managing redirects to a subdomain after authentication in a React/Rails application using React Router

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, .htaccess, reactjs, react-router

I have a React single page application using React Router that hooks into a Rails 5 API. The Rails application uses [devise_token_auth](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth) for authentication. I've successfully created an authentication process that stores the user state in a Redux store on the client side.

Each user of the application belongs to a company. Each company has its own unique subdomain (e.g., *companya.foo.com*, *companyb.foo.com*). A user should be redirected to their company subdomain after signing in from *foo.com*. All requests for an authenticated user should keep them on their own subdomain. Users should be redirected back to *foo.com* when they sign out.

I read that this is impossible with React Router and the browser API but there has to be a way to achieve this. I also saw some *.htaccess* suggestions but I am unfamiliar with this approach and I'm not sure if this will handle dynamic redirects.

What is the most intuitive approach to solve this problem?

Comment: Hi, It's almost 3 years a little too late but did you find how to do it and if yes do you mind sharing it as an answer?

Comment: @HermannHH ... I too am curious what your solution was.  Please share!

Comment: @hugo I never actually ended up figuring it out. I rather settled on having a url param rather than a subdomain. Seemed simpler

Comment: What an interesting question. I am not familiar with Rails but can help on the React side.

Could you add to your question the snippet of code involving React Router that you wrote for this?

I'm curious about the fact that you have different subdomains. Does a different React application live at *companya.foo.com* and *foo.com* or is it the same app that handles the frontend of both of these URLs?

As far as I understand, *.htaccess* is for Apache servers only. Does your app run on Apache or do you have a different platform to serve your app?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to redirect to the subdomain and pass the authentication token in the params to keep the user logged in